# Google Charts: how to deal with monthly data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Charts to present monthly data in a stacked column chart.
I'd like to use `Date` values for the x-axis, since Google Charts is smart about labels and gridlines.  But you can only specify exact days in a Javascript `Date`, not a whole month.

In my first attempt, I simply always used the first day of the month.  But then the January bar straddles the year gridline (e.g. January 2020 is on the gridline separating 2019 and 2020) which just looks funny.

My second attempt uses day 15 for every month.  That looks a bit better.

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'nl'});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
    function drawChart2() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["","Appels","Peren","Bananen","dec?"],[new Date(2018, 0, 15),5217,4162,3014,0],[new Date(2018, 1, 15),4691,3582,2552,0],[new Date(2018, 2, 15),5427,4651,4160,0],[new Date(2018, 3, 15),4272,3571,3765,0],[new Date(2018, 4, 15),4409,3266,3020,0],[new Date(2018, 5, 15),4566,3566,3131,0],[new Date(2018, 6, 15),4628,3329,3742,0],[new Date(2018, 7, 15),4175,3309,3390,0],[new Date(2018, 8, 15),4794,3695,3047,0],[new Date(2018, 9, 15),5075,3976,2856,0],[new Date(2018, 10, 15),7568,6737,3056,0],[new Date(2018, 11, 15),7978,7551,4634,0],[new Date(2019, 0, 15),5300,5101,3730,0],[new Date(2019, 1, 15),4526,4310,3342,0],[new Date(2019, 2, 15),5399,5053,4335,0],[new Date(2019, 3, 15),4380,4187,4045,0],[new Date(2019, 4, 15),4940,4560,3854,0],[new Date(2019, 5, 15),4819,4529,3617,0],[new Date(2019, 6, 15),5158,4723,4783,0],[new Date(2019, 7, 15),4813,4290,3673,0],[new Date(2019, 8, 15),5935,5147,3504,0],[new Date(2019, 9, 15),5886,5362,3620,0],[new Date(2019, 10, 15),8565,7706,5652,0],[new Date(2019, 11, 15),9373,8416,4719,0],[new Date(2020, 0, 15),6054,6173,4367,0],[new Date(2020, 1, 15),5691,5458,4340,0],[new Date(2020, 2, 15),14864,6467,8200,0],[new Date(2020, 3, 15),21182,9031,7064,0],[new Date(2020, 4, 15),16590,9828,6981,0],[new Date(2020, 5, 15),13621,10060,7240,0],[new Date(2020, 6, 15),9966,7411,6878,0],[new Date(2020, 7, 15),9771,6948,6265,0],[new Date(2020, 8, 15),11033,7584,4794,0],[new Date(2020, 9, 15),13606,8981,5241,0],[new Date(2020, 10, 15),24279,11658,5889,0],[new Date(2020, 11, 15),2615,1523,439,49463]]);
      var options = {'title':'Consumptie per maand',
                     'titleTextStyle': { 'fontSize': 15 },
                     'width':640,
                     'height':240,
                     'legend': { 'position':'bottom' },
                     'series': {"0":{"color":"66aabb"},"1":{"color":"66ddee"},"3":{"color":"e8f8ff"},"2":{"color":"bbeeff"}},
                     'chartArea': { 'width': '90%', 'left': 60, 'right': 20 },
                     'bar': { 'groupWidth': '80%' },
                     'isStacked':true};
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 640px; height: 240px;" id="chart2"></div>
```

However, the tooltips now show the exact date, e.g. “15 jan. 2020”.  I can't find a way to customize that (except by using custom HTML tooltips, which would be a bit of a hassle – and that don't look as pretty as the default tooltips).

Is there a better way to deal with monthly data in Google Charts?
(Of course, I can just use string values (e.g. `'jan. 2020'`), but then I lost the smart x-axis labels and gridlines that using `Date` values provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [DateFormat class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat), to format the date values.

by default, the tooltip will display the formatted value.

create the date format using a format pattern...

```
var formatMonth = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
});
```

then use the `format` method to format the data table column...
`format(dataTable, columnIndex)`

```
formatMonth.format(data, 0);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  language: 'nl'
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["","Appels","Peren","Bananen","dec?"],[new Date(2018, 0, 15),5217,4162,3014,0],[new Date(2018, 1, 15),4691,3582,2552,0],[new Date(2018, 2, 15),5427,4651,4160,0],[new Date(2018, 3, 15),4272,3571,3765,0],[new Date(2018, 4, 15),4409,3266,3020,0],[new Date(2018, 5, 15),4566,3566,3131,0],[new Date(2018, 6, 15),4628,3329,3742,0],[new Date(2018, 7, 15),4175,3309,3390,0],[new Date(2018, 8, 15),4794,3695,3047,0],[new Date(2018, 9, 15),5075,3976,2856,0],[new Date(2018, 10, 15),7568,6737,3056,0],[new Date(2018, 11, 15),7978,7551,4634,0],[new Date(2019, 0, 15),5300,5101,3730,0],[new Date(2019, 1, 15),4526,4310,3342,0],[new Date(2019, 2, 15),5399,5053,4335,0],[new Date(2019, 3, 15),4380,4187,4045,0],[new Date(2019, 4, 15),4940,4560,3854,0],[new Date(2019, 5, 15),4819,4529,3617,0],[new Date(2019, 6, 15),5158,4723,4783,0],[new Date(2019, 7, 15),4813,4290,3673,0],[new Date(2019, 8, 15),5935,5147,3504,0],[new Date(2019, 9, 15),5886,5362,3620,0],[new Date(2019, 10, 15),8565,7706,5652,0],[new Date(2019, 11, 15),9373,8416,4719,0],[new Date(2020, 0, 15),6054,6173,4367,0],[new Date(2020, 1, 15),5691,5458,4340,0],[new Date(2020, 2, 15),14864,6467,8200,0],[new Date(2020, 3, 15),21182,9031,7064,0],[new Date(2020, 4, 15),16590,9828,6981,0],[new Date(2020, 5, 15),13621,10060,7240,0],[new Date(2020, 6, 15),9966,7411,6878,0],[new Date(2020, 7, 15),9771,6948,6265,0],[new Date(2020, 8, 15),11033,7584,4794,0],[new Date(2020, 9, 15),13606,8981,5241,0],[new Date(2020, 10, 15),24279,11658,5889,0],[new Date(2020, 11, 15),2615,1523,439,49463]]);

  var formatMonth = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });
  formatMonth.format(data, 0);

  var options = {'title':'Consumptie per maand',
                 'titleTextStyle': { 'fontSize': 15 },
                 'width':640,
                 'height':240,
                 'legend': { 'position':'bottom' },
                 'series': {"0":{"color":"66aabb"},"1":{"color":"66ddee"},"3":{"color":"e8f8ff"},"2":{"color":"bbeeff"}},
                 'chartArea': { 'width': '90%', 'left': 60, 'right': 20 },
                 'bar': { 'groupWidth': '80%' },
                 'isStacked':true};
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart2"></div>
```

---

NOTE: formatting the data table sets the formatted value of each cell of the data table column.

you can also provide the formatted value directly in the data by using object notation.
if you wanted, you could load the data table rows as follows...

```
[{v: new Date(2018, 0, 15), f: 'jan 2018'},5217,4162,3014,0]
```

where `v:` is the value, and `f:` is the formatted value...